# Run an IHostedService function during the Start of application but only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, startup, background-task, ihostedservice

I have a need to `run a function` only `once` every time the application start (the function checks for a particular `Mongo collection` in my DB and insert in documents that are predefined by myself).

`IHostedService/BackgroundService` seemingly was able to do the job. I just need to inject the service into my Startup.cs file.

However, I was wondering if there are anyways that I can gracefully achieve this task since `IHostedService` is really made to implement more of a `cron job` (a task that needs to run in an interval of time say, every 30 minutes).

Thank you.

Comment: I am not understanding your reasoning for not simply using an `IHostedService`? Your explanation of *since IHostedService are really made to implement more of a cron job* is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Basically, using an `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService` is the only *proper* way to do what you are wanting to do.

Comment: If you just need to run a function at the start of the application, you do not need a Backgroundjob or HostedService. For example, if you either use ASP.net Core API project or even any type of other project type, just call your method in **program.cs** or in **startup.cs**. you can easily get the required services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want just by using IHostedService.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //logic
        }
```

And in Startup.cs this is how I register my service.

```
AddSingleton<IHostedService, myService>
```

I ran my application and it debug into the AddSingleton line and only run the ExecuteAsync function once. So that is my solution.

Comment: You need to call it like this: `services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>()`. Then the framework will execute it properly.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Misunderstanding, a single task must be executed after the application has started.

There are multiples ways to solve it, but I will go for [IHostApplicationLifetime::ApplicationStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). You can create an extension method to register the function you will execute on startup.

```
public static class HostExtensions
{
    public static void CheckMongoCollectionOnStarted(this IHost host)
    {
        var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var lifetime = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();
        var loggerFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
        var logger = loggerFactory!.CreateLogger("CheckMongoCollectionOnStarted");
        lifetime!.ApplicationStarted.Register(
            async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("CheckMongoCollectionOnStarted started");
                    //TODO: add your logic here
                    await Task.Delay(2000); //simulate working
                    logger.LogInformation("CheckMongoCollectionOnStarted completed");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //shutdown if fail?
                    logger.LogCritical(ex, "An error has occurred while checking the Mongo collection. Shutting down the application...");
                    lifetime.StopApplication();
                }
                finally
                {
                    scope.Dispose();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then call the extension from your `Program` class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.CheckMongoCollectionOnStarted();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I only need to run the task once everytime application start and not needed any kind of interval. How should I implement it? Would Task.Result() work or should I just return a boolean to indicate the task has run succesfully and then pass in the cancellation token?

Comment: Sorry @Noelia I understand now. Well, you can use BackgroundService, IHostApplicationLifetime::ApplicationStarted, IStartupFilter  and configure a middleware to run after the standard configurations, or you can play with your `Program.cs` creating a scope and running your checks. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: @Noelia, please check the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Why would you do it this way in leu of just creating an `IHostedService` ?

Comment: @Andy the `IHostedService:StartAsync(CancellationToken)` is invoked before `Startup.Configure` and before the server has started (`IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted`). You can change this behavior, but you will need to modify the `CreateDefaultBuilder` function. Also, you will need to register the `IHostedService` on `Startup.ConfigureServices`. The `IHostedService` is commonly used to run a long background task, in this case @Noelia wants to run a single task after the application has started.

Comment: What? How could it be invoked before startup.configure? That's impossible. You need to site sources. I would hate for you to be spreading misinformation.

Comment: @Andy my sources are always trusted: MSDN, Microsoft. Please, [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface). You can create and register an `IHostedService` and put 2 breakpoints (`Startup.Configure` and `IHostedService:StartAsync`) and you will be surprised.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I want just by using IHostedService.
```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //logic
        }
```
Startup.cs
```